# ( find Distance and display ) in Arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array

Any suggestion on writing proper codes to get distance between `src` and `dest` and Display the `distance` to user .

---

```
    int distance = findDistance(CityNames, distances, src, dest);
        display(distance);
    }

    public static int findDistance(String[] CityNames, int[][] distances, String src, String dest) {
        // Find and return the distance between src and dest.
        return 0;
    }

    public static void display(int distance) {
        // Display the distance to user.
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: what is this for? If this part of an app you are building, then look at Google Maps API.

Comment: hi ramesh , it is just simple practical code i am doing on 2D array , i need to write some codes where i made a comment : // Find and return the distance between src and dest. and // Display the distance to user.

Comment: function findDistance hast to find index of two cities and it will return the index .

Comment: @yash , Every week , i am going  to post challenge coding questions and i will come up with answer by end of each week , if you know any developers / programmer community that they like to join this coding challenges let me get involve with those group so we can come up with some nice efficient way of coding on each project .

Answer (score 0):

```
package test; // sample of array w/o validation .

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int distances[][] = {{0, 50, 100, 20}, {50, 0, 70, 110}, {100, 70, 0, 200}, {20, 110, 200, 0}};
        String cityNames[] = {"herndon", "fairfax", "baltimore", "centerville"};

        String departure = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter departure city");
        String destination = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter destination city");
        int departureIndex = findCity(departure, cityNames);
        int destinationIndex = findCity(destination, cityNames);
        display(departureIndex, destinationIndex, distances);
    }





    private static int findCity(String cityName, String[] cityNames) {

        for (int i = 0; i < cityNames.length; i++) {
            if (cityName.equalsIgnoreCase(cityNames[i]))
            {
                return i;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }


    private static void display(int departureIndex, int destinationIndex, int[][] distances) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Distance is " + distances[departureIndex][destinationIndex]);
    }


}
```